How do I efficiently query for existence in Amazon Neptune with Gremlin?
My application, which is built on a Gremlin graph database, uses graph query expressions for security policies, very similar to the following:
boolean hasPermission(String principal, String photoId) {
  g.V(principal).hasLabel('CognitoUser')
    .out('Authenticates').hasLabel('UserAccount')
    .out('Owns').hasLabel('Photo')
    .hasId(photoId)
    .hasNext()
}

I do not care about any values or data return other than "does a match exist?" Since Neptune operates in a transaction-per-request mode, I expected these to be efficient and garbage-collected quickly, but it appears that for some reason they are retained indefinitely, leading to a memory leak on the server instance.
When running against Neptune, how should I structure an existence query such as this one so that the server cleans up the resources used to execute the query as soon as it returns the true/false answer?

I believe what you have is right... How do you know there's a memory leak? Does something stop working?

@tim_yates When running these queries, the freeable memory available in the Neptune instance declines linearly, and it never recovers; if the memory gets too low, the Neptune engine crashes. I've tried stressing the engine and then leaving it alone, and it never garbage-collects.

FreeableMemory in Amazon Neptune does not release memory in the way you are thinking.  Due to the internals of how Neptune works memory allocations are not necessarily returned to be garbage collected and are instead reused.   This means that the FreeableMemory metric reported does not always reflect the memory available for querying as it may be reused.  A high level of FreeableMemory usage is to be expected in most circumstances and does not mean that there is a memory leak.
